# What is the toolkit that implements Cost sensitive Support Vector Machine?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick, libsvm

I need implementation of cost sensitive support vector machine. The cost is different for each training example (unlike each class). So problem is to solve 
$max_\alpha$ $-1/2 \sum_{i,j} \alpha_i\alpha_jY_iY_jK(X_i,X_j) + \sum_i \alpha_i $
s.t. $0 <= \alpha_i <= c_i \forall i$
So are there any implementation (like LIBSVM, SVMlight) available to implement such SVM (where cost is different for each training point)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/#weights_for_data_instances